# SparkSession: ActiveSession vs DefaultSession

Tags: apache-spark

According to the API docs:

> `getActiveSession`() Returns the active SparkSession for the current
>   thread, returned by the builder.
>
> `getDefaultSession`() Returns the
>   default SparkSession that is returned by the builder.

I was (most likely erroneously) using `getActiveSession` to retrieve the `SparkSession` or `SparkContext` in some functions across multiple threads. Sometimes the activeSession was not defined (most likely because the thread had just started up).

Can someone explain the difference between the two, or is the API doc sufficiently self-explanatory?

Also, when would I use `getActiveSession` if

1. In 99% of apps there is only one session and
2. `getDefaultSession` should return that session

Comment: This was wildly confusing, thanks for asking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `ActiveSession` is for single thread while `DefaultSession` is global. The `DefaultSession` is the `ActiveSession` for main thread by default.
- Each `SparkSession` object share the same `SparkContext`. But they may have different states, like SQL configurations, temporary tables and registered functions.
- `In 99% of apps there is only one session`, you are right, in fact, more than 99%.
- When you may need `ActiveSession`?

  - Consider you are handling 100 cities data parallelly in 4 threads with Spark SQL.
  - If you always use the `DefaultSession`, you must use different name for each dataframe like `city_1`, `city_2`.
  - With `ActiveSession`(you can create new session by `SparkSession.newSession`), you can register all the temp views with the same name `city`, everything goes easy.
- Besides, the helper `SparkSession.active` can help you fall to `DefaultSession` when `ActiveSession` not exist

Comment: thanks a million. It is interesting that this took two years to get an informd answer. Appreciate this

Comment: there is no `SparkSession.getDefaultSession()` method: was it deprecated/removed?

Comment: ` SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()`   use this.