# Why would i need multiple sparksessions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to get my head around sparksession and sparkcontext, and came across the idea of multiple sparksessions per spark application, but couldn't understand why would i need many sparksessions? this also let me think of how many dataframes we're allowed to create per sparksession?

I'd be grateful if someone could give a concrete example from real life experience?

Comment: Each spark session should be an isolated spark app running on the cluster. Also, you could create multiple sessions, each of which connected to a different cluster.

Comment: I think this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511888/sparksession-activesession-vs-defaultsession